# RecylcerView GridLayoutManager where views span all the space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using `GridLayoutManager` with `RecylcerView` and it has 2 columns.

Each view has the following:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:width="wrap_content"
     android:height="wrap_content">

     <Imageview
         android:width="100dp"
         android:height="150dp" />
</Linearlayout>
```

Obviously each image has the allocated size which results in a big separation between the columns
What do I need to do so the image views take all the available areas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code for your XML file:

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="wrap_content">
   <Imageview
     android:width="match_parent" 
     android:height="wrap_content"/>
</Linearlayout>
```

Comment: It does not work, nothing gets displayed as one row seems to take over